# Apache POI Excelsheet to pdf file

Tags: apache-poi, spreadsheet

How can I save a defined excel spreedsheet (e.g. Tabelle1) with printlayout on one page (.setFitToPage) as pdf-file

```
  HSSFWorkbook workBook = null;
  try {
    workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("/total-ae-chem.xls"));
  } 
  catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
  } 
  catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workBook.getSheet("Tabelle1");
```

Comment: What do you expect as an answer? Does `apache poi` provide methods to convert `Excel` to `PDF`? No, it does not. `Apache poi` provides methods to read cell values and cell styles from `Excel`. After that or while that those values would must be wrote into a `PDF` using appropriate java libraries. Can the code for doing that be in an answer here? No, it can't. Much too broad and dependent on which java `PDF` librarie was chosen.